# The following occured when trying to install sas software

Tags: java, .net, spring

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean
>       at
>       at

Comment: What build system do you use?

Comment: @matt i used Apache ANT

Comment: Have you configured other dependencies yet, e.g. ``spring-core`` or ``junit``? You need to add the spring-beans to your classpath.

Comment: how can i add spring-beans to the path and what version of spring-beans

Comment: You will need several dependencies of Spring, best all of them in the same version. The missing class you posted is probably only the beginning. Integrating a build system is not trivial and cannot be answered right here. I'd propose you take a look at http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ .

Comment: ok many thanks i will revert back to you